# ASP.NET Core - Authentice with Microsoft Dynamics using ADFS

Tags: c#, active-directory, asp.net-core, microsoft-dynamics, adfs

I am trying to authenticate against Microsoft Dynamics so I can access it's OData API. I have accomplished this in other projects but these projects are .Net Framework 4.5.2.

I now need to be able to do the same thing with .Net Core but I'm having trouble implementing this.

Users are authenticated via ADFS so I don't want to be dealing with registering apps in Azure and using client IDs and client secrets. It's been possible to do this without these before so it should be possible now. This is how I am doing it in .Net Framework 4.5.2:

```
var result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
                    authConfig.LoginResource,
                    authConfig.ClientId,
                    new UserPasswordCredential(authConfig.Username, authConfig.Password)
                ).Result;
```

The problem is that UserPasswordCredential is no longer supported by design so I can no longer authenticate this way. I believe that this may be possible by using the generic ASP.Net Core OAuth authentication library but I'm not sure how I would translate what I have already into such a solution.

Comment: I am assuming authConfig is your web.config or app.config file......is LoginResource a path to a certificate or other external file?  The error is IO so that would indicate a problem accessing some external resource but without more information via full stack trace or additional code it would be difficult to identify the problem.

Comment: I have solved the DLL issue. It was caused by not using the latest .NET Core libraries. I am now stuck trying to authenticate with Dynamics. I'm getting an error saying a Password was expected but obviously I am unable to provide one now.